# How to create batch file?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I need to run the below command from command prompt. How do i make it a batch file so that I do not have to type the whole command again?

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft ajax Minifier\ajaxmin.exe c:\css\reset.css c:\css\main-styles.css c:\css\lightbox.css c:\css\shortcodes.css c:\css\custom-fonts.css c:\css\custom-colors.css c:\css\admin_menu.min.css -out c:\css\mc.css -clobber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `>"file.bat" echo` to the start of the command to create a simple batch file.

Quotes around paths and filenames with spaces and `&` characters are needed too.

```
 >"file.bat" echo "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft ajax Minifier\ajaxmin.exe" c:\css\reset.css c:\css\main-styles.css c:\css\lightbox.css c:\css\shortcodes.css c:\css\custom-fonts.css c:\css\custom-colors.css c:\css\admin_menu.min.css -out c:\css\mc.css -clobber
```

In some cases certain characters will need escaping but for your example it will work.

Comment: I've never seen it done this way round before. This does result in a leading space before the command for some reason.

Comment: @Ashigore Yes, I noticed that I'd used a less common method - so I changed it to another method which is used more often.

Comment: I have updated the command, actually ajaxmin.exe is defined in a c: program files ...

Comment: See my edit - you also need to double quote paths with spaces and `&`

Comment: It is creating the file.bat file but not running the actual command when i douple click file.bat

Comment: That's correct and is how batch files work.  You create the batch file and then run it a zillion times afterward. :)  You can create a batch file in Notepad and other text editors too.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new file with a .bat extension and copy these lines into it.

Then you can run it by double clicking it in Windows explorer or by typing its name in cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, by the looks of it you are already running that command from a command prompt, you can write the command to a batch file like this:

```
echo <command> > mycommand.bat
```

So:

```
echo ajaxmin.exe c:\css\reset.css c:\css\main-styles.css c:\css\lightbox.css c:\css\shortcodes.css c:\css\custom-fonts.css c:\css\custom-colors.css c:\css\admin_menu.min.css -out c:\css\mc.css -clobber > mycommand.bat
```

You can also type the command into notepad or other text editor and save with a .bat extension instead of .txt.

Answer (score 0):

How to create a Batch file:

1. Right click on your desktop or whereever you want it to
2. Click new text document
3. Rename it
4. Open it in notepad or whatever you want, and now you have a batch file!